# Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 12 The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query returns an error:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(200);

--SELECT @x = '13/12/2019 16:01:47'
SELECT @x = '-'

select  CASE WHEN ISDATE(@x)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, @x)  else case when @x='-' then '-' else CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@x,10),105),101) END END;
```

If I run this query it works fine:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(200);

SELECT @x = '13/12/2019 16:01:47'
--SELECT @x = '-'

 select  CASE WHEN ISDATE(@x)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, @x)  else case when @x='-' then '-' else CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@x,10),105),101) END END;
```

Tried this query as well:

```
SELECT case when @x = '-' then '-' 
            WHEN ISDATE(@x)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, @x)  
            else  CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@x,10),105),101) 
        END
```

I don't understand how to handle '-' in case statement. Everything looks fine to me. I need to check the condition in the case statement.

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have something like try_cast?

Comment: Let's look at the last statement using CASE. CASE is an expression and it returns a value of a specific and single datatype. You can't return both a string ('-') and a datetime value based on conditions. You must decide which datatype you want and then write the code to convert all the different possibilities as needed. This smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should probably reconsider your goal and the decisions that brought you to this path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @x),
       COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@x, 10), 105), 101), '-')
```

I don't see an advantage to converting back to a string.

Comment: It gives an error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.